# Issue with powershell output ad-computer foreach

Tags: powershell

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "LT*" -or $_.Name -like "PC*" -or $_.Name -like "MC*"} | Select name,lastlogondate

"You have [{0}] computers in domain [{1}]" -f $computers.count, (get-addomain).dnsroot

$today = Get-Date
$monthago = $today.AddDays(-30)
"Looking for systems that have not logged in since $monthago"

foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
   if ($computer.lastlogondate -lt $monthago)
      {"Computer [$computer] suspect" 
       "last logon $($computer.lastlogondate)"
       ""}
}
```

returns the following result:

> Computer [@{name=lt020367; lastlogondate=10/23/2019 11:45:38}] suspect
>   last logon 10/23/2019 11:45:38

Can someone possibly tell me why my output is resulting in [@{ and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by `get-adcomputer [...] | Select name,lastlogondate` you are creating an `object`. To output properties of those objects, simply use:

```
"Computer [$($computer.name)] suspect" 
"last logon $($computer.lastlogondate)"
```

By the way:
Getting all `*` properties is not ideal. Always filter as early as you can: `-properties lastlogondate` (name is always returned). Same goes for `-filter "name -like 'LT*' -or name -like 'PC*' -or name -like 'MC*'"`.
Also be careful as lastlogondate of computer objects in AD is not synced between domain controllers.